# unit testing and mocking then methods in promises

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, promise, jasmine

If one has a piece of logic to be unit tested with various sequential promises, how does one go about actually asserting on the logic within the `then(() => {})` functions? With a similar setup to below I run into issues where the first test will pass but the second test does not. I am curious as to *why* the anonymous then block in the implementation is never reached.

```
//Implementation
class FiddleService {
    constructor(dependencies = {}) {
        const { someService = new SomeService() } = dependencies;
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    doSomething(params) {
        this.someService.asyncOperation1(params).then((result) => {
            ...
            //never gets called by spy in test
            return this.someService.asyncOperation2(result.firstName);
        }).then((result) => {
            return this.someService.asyncOperation3(result.age);
        });
    }
}
//test
describe("FiddleService", () => {
    let someService;
    beforeAll(() => {
        someService = new SomeService();
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation1).and
          .returnValue(new Promise(() => {firstName: "Jan"});
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation2).and
          .returnValue(new Promise(() => {age: 50});
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation3);
    });

    it("calls asyncOperation1", () => {
        let fiddleService = new FiddleService();
        fiddleService.doSomething({});
        expect(someService.asyncOperation1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it("calls asyncOperation2", () => {
        let fiddleService = new FiddleService();
        fiddleService.doSomething({});
        expect(someService.asyncOperation2).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: Those two `new Promise(() => ...)` expressions return promises that will never be resolved. `Promise.resolve(...)`, in two places, would seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

as @roamer-1888 said the solution was related to calling the promises and calling done in the tests.

```
//test
describe("FiddleService", () => {
    let someService;
    beforeAll(() => {
        someService = new SomeService();
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation1).and
          .returnValue(new Promise(() => {firstName: "Jan"});
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation2).and
          .returnValue(new Promise(() => {age: 50});
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation3);
    });

    it("calls asyncOperation1", () => {
        let fiddleService = new FiddleService();
        fiddleService.doSomething({});
        expect(someService.asyncOperation1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it("calls asyncOperation2", (done) => {
        let fiddleService = new FiddleService();
        fiddleService.doSomething({}).then(_ => {
            expect(someService.asyncOperation2).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I helped much but hey, it's great to get a mention, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine isn't a main part of my skill-set so this is offered tentatively.

I still think you need `Promise.resolve()` instead of `new Promise()`, in two places, and think you can exploit Jasmine's ability to handle multiple expect()s in a single test, without loss of information.

```
//test
describe("FiddleService", () => {
    let someService;
    beforeAll(() => {
        someService = new SomeService();
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation1).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({firstName: "Jan"}));
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation2).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({age: 50}));
        spyOn(someService.asyncOperation3);
    });

    it("should make three sequential async calls", (done) => {
        let fiddleService = new FiddleService();
        fiddleService.doSomething({}).then(_ => {
            expect(someService.asyncOperation1).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(someService.asyncOperation2).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(someService.asyncOperation3).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        });
    });
});
```